# How to set posframe as active?

Tags: frames, posframe

Is there some option to make frame active when i create it? I can switch to it with this code, but maybe there's a way to do this without `select-frame` func?

```el
(defun show-misc-posframe ()
  (when (posframe-workable-p)
    (posframe-show "*spec-buffer*"
           :poshandler 'posframe-poshandler-frame-top-right-corner
           :height 45
           :width 50
           :override-parameters '((cursor-type box))))
  (setq misc-posframe--frame (with-current-buffer "*spec-buffer*"
                    posframe--frame))
  (select-frame misc-posframe--frame))
```

Comment: `make-frame`; `with-selected-frame` ....; `select-frame` / `raise-frame`; `select-frame-set-input-focus`; ....  The doc-string for the function `make-frame` states in part:  "*On graphical displays, this function does not itself make the new
frame the selected frame.  However, the window system may select
the new frame according to its own rules.*"